# Rabbitmq asynchronous queue consumption

Tags: java, asynchronous, queue, rabbitmq

I'm working on this tutorial : http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html

And if I execute the following instructions :

```
1 > java java -cp $CP ReceiveLogsTopic 1
2 > java java -cp $CP ReceiveLogsTopic 2
3 > java -cp $CP EmitLogTopic 1 a
```

The message "a" is received by the consumer and displayed.

But if I do this :

```
1 > java java -cp $CP ReceiveLogsTopic 1
2 > java -cp $CP EmitLogTopic 1 a
3 > java java -cp $CP ReceiveLogsTopic 2
4 > java -cp $CP EmitLogTopic 2 b
```

Only message "b" is displayed because the consumer is declared before the producer.

So my question is, is there a way to declare a queue "asychronous" and force it to keeps messages in the queue until a consumer read it ?

Sincerely

Comment: I've been attempting to solve the very same problem for like a day now. Is it even possible? Have you found anything out since asking this question?

Comment: I switched for a small home made code, rabbitmq was actually way too big for my current needs. I only keep this question open because it might be helpful in the future.